# Using a keyhole contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I've noticed that some complex analysis textbooks discuss evaluating real-valued integrals like $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}} \, dx $ using a [keyhole contour](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Keyhole_contour.svg)  before they have defined the Cauchy principal value of an integral ([first definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)).

But isn't using a keyhole contour a principal value approach in the sense that the contour approaches the singularity at the origin in a symmetrical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use a keyhole contour is to do with the fact that $z^{1/2}$ has a branch point at the origin.

You don't really need to know the concept of Cauchy Principal Value to be able to take the limit of the inner radius going to $0$.

But, in a way you are right that it is a principal value approach.

Comment: Using the example I gave, it would seem to me that by letting the radius of the inner circle go to 0, what you end up calculating is $\text{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}} \ dx$.  Then you can argue that you can drop the PV sign. But some textbooks don't seem to look at it that way, and it's quite confusing.

Comment: @Random: I was talking about the integral on the inner "circle". As a real/complex integral, the integral you gave is well defined and PV does not appear, that looks right.